# Cannot run .FormulaArray, however the code works as a regular formula

Tags: arrays, vba, formula

I have a VBA code that creates an array formula, however currently it creates a run-time error '1004' (Unable to set the FormulaArray propert of the Range class) when I run the script. I've included the working excel formula below as well.

The odd thing is that the formula works if I use a simple .FormulaR1C1 syntax in the code the script runs fine. Once the formula is in the excel spreadsheet and I open the formula and click "CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER" it works just fine. 
The code is below, I'm guessing the IF statements in the formula is the cause of the error.

Can any of you see that I'm doing wrong?

Thank you! :)

```
Set rng53 = Worksheets("Settings").Range("N42")
rng53.Offset(r1).FormulaArray = "=IFERROR(IF(Settings!R39C7=Admin!R7C17,INDEX(Dimensions!R5C18:R4171C18,MATCH(RC7&RC9,Dimensions!R5C6:R4171C6&Dimensions!R5C12:R4171C12,0)),IF(Settings!R39C7=Admin!R8C17,INDEX(Dimensions!R5C18:R4171C18,MATCH(RC7&RC11&RC13,Dimensions!R5C6:R4171C6&Dimensions!R5C15:R4171C15&Dimensions!R5C17:R4171C17,0)),""Error"")),""N/A"")"

Working Excel formula:
{=IFERROR(IF(Settings!$G$39=Admin!$Q$7,INDEX(Dimensions!$R$5:$R$4171,MATCH($G42&$I42,Dimensions!$F$5:$F$4171&Dimensions!$L$5:$L$4171,0)),IF(Settings!$G$39=Admin!$Q$8,INDEX(Dimensions!$R$5:$R$4171,MATCH($G42&$K42&$M42,Dimensions!$F$5:$F$4171&Dimensions!$O$5:$O$4171&Dimensions!$Q$5:$Q$4171,0)),"Error")),"N/A")}
```

Answer (score 0):

FormulaArray property has a character limit of 255.
The length of your formula is 310.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837104.aspx